# remove element by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a element that append to **body** when user click on a button.
I want to remove appended element by clicking on it. How can I  do this?

> Code

```js
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
      $("body").append("<div class='someClass'></div>");
  });
  $(".someClass").click(function() {
      $(this).remove();
  });
```

```css
.someClass{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">append div</button>
```

Comment: You need to use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$(document).on('click','.someClass', function(){...}` syntax. This is because when the JQuery is loaded the element with class `someClass` do not exist in DOM. And you want to associate a `click` event into it. Thus, you need to listen for `click` of that element from `document` level so that when `.someClass` element is added in DOM it recognise the `click` event for it.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("body").append("<div class='someClass'></div>"); 
});
$(document).on('click','.someClass', function(){
  $(this).remove(); 
});
```

```css
.someClass{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">append div</button>
```

Comment: Why does my code not work?

Comment: @Majid read the answer. I have mentioned that reason. `This is because when ...`

Comment: You should have voted to close the question

Comment: @Majid read the link I put in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `click` event will only apply to elements that already exist. Because you are adding elements dynamically you will need to use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead. This will add the event to both existing elements and elements that are dynamically added later on.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(){
    $("body").append("<div class='someClass'></div>");  
});
```